# How to migrate from JBoss Portal to GateIn?

Tags: java, jboss, portlet, gatein, jboss-portal

I am new to GateIn portal.

We have developed portal using JBoss Portal 2.7, which has simple UIs.

How can I migrate my portal application from JBoss portal 2.7 to GateIn final release?

From where to get the idea about how to create a new simple portal using gatein and all the configuration that need to be done for that.

Comment: What type of application? Is it a portlet?

Comment: @tmarwen yes it is portlet

Comment: @tmarwen i want to know the configurations that i have to done in gatein as its totally different than jboss portal

Comment: You can check my answer, and upvote it if it helped better getting the thing. If you have a specific issue, please address it in a separate ticket.

Answer (score 0):

If your portlet/web application is based on *EJB* Components, then it can only be deployed on an application server, such as JBoss, which underlies all Entreprise Edition features.

GateIn portal is nothing but a portlet container, internally a web applcation that must be deployed in an application server such as Tomcat AS or JBoss AS, but a full EE Server is a must in order to have all entreprise java beans and services functional.

So the essence is, if you are using EJBs in your development, then you can only use an Applciation server with EJB container.